# Why can't I install coreutils:armhf alongside coreutils

Tags: apt, cross-compilation, crossplatform

I am trying to install `coreutils:armhf` on my machine I am cross compiling for `armhf` architecture. When I execute

```
sudo apt-get install coreutils:armhf
```

Ubuntu tells me

```
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
    coreutils
```

I just want `coreutils:armhf` binaries to be installed in the correct directories, so I can copy them onto my target easily. I don't want to replace my native coreutils binaries with armhf architecture ones.

Comment: What are these "correct directories"? It seems you don't want to install them but just download them?